# I Can't Install Pyaudio

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

I'm trying to install pyaudio with `pip3 install pyaudio` in Ubuntu Mate. But I get an error. How to fix the error?

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyaudio ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-sdstw2l2/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpxh6_2az5pip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.6
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.6
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.6/src
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
  src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
   #include "portaudio.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-sdstw2l2/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-tccnyizi-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.6
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.6
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.6/src
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
     #include "portaudio.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-sdstw2l2/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-tccnyizi-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-sdstw2l2/pyaudio/
```

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54396790/435093 — have you done a web search for the error first?

Answer (score 2):

from https://github.com/HackerShackOfficial/AI-Smart-Mirror/issues/23

sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev

pip3 install pyaudio